# removing duplicate units from data frame

Tags: r, bigdata, duplicates

I'm working on a large dataset with n covariates. Many of the rows are duplicates. In order to identify the duplicates I need to use a subset of the covariates to create an identification variable. That is, (n-x) covariates are irrelevant. I want to concatenate the values on the x covariates to uniquely identify the observations and eliminate the duplicates.

```
set.seed(1234)
UNIT <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6)
DATE <- c("1/1/2010","1/1/2010","1/1/2010","1/2/2012","1/2/2009","1/2/2004","1/2/2005","1/2/2005",
      "1/1/2011","1/1/2011","1/1/2011","1/1/2009","1/1/2008","1/1/2008","1/1/2012","1/1/2013",
      "1/1/2012")
OUT1 <- c(300,400,400,400,600,700,700,800,800,800,900,700,700,100,100,100,500)
JUNK1 <- c(rnorm(17,0,1))
JUNK2 <- c(rnorm(17,0,1))

test = data.frame(UNIT,DATE,OUT1,JUNK1,JUNK2)
```

'test' is a sample data frame. The variables I need to use to uniquely identify the observations are 'UNIT', 'DATE' and 'OUT1'. For example,

```
head(test)
  UNIT     DATE OUT1      JUNK1      JUNK2
1    1 1/1/2010  300 -1.2070657 -0.9111954
2    1 1/1/2010  400  0.2774292 -0.8371717
3    1 1/1/2010  400  1.0844412  2.4158352
4    1 1/2/2012  400 -2.3456977  0.1340882
5    2 1/2/2009  600  0.4291247 -0.4906859
6    2 1/2/2004  700  0.5060559 -0.4405479
```

Observations 1 and 4 are not a duplicate in the dataset. Observations 2 and 3 are duplicates. The new dataset I want to create would keep observations 1 and 4 and *only one* of 2 and 3. The solution I have tried is:

```
subset(test, !duplicated(c(UNIT,DATE,OUT1)))
```

Which unfortunately does not do the trick:

```
      UNIT     DATE OUT1       JUNK1      JUNK2
1        1 1/1/2010  300 -1.20706575 -0.9111954
5        2 1/2/2009  600  0.42912469 -0.4906859
8        3 1/2/2005  800 -0.54663186 -0.6937202
11       4 1/1/2011  900 -0.47719270 -1.0236557
14       5 1/1/2008  100  0.06445882  1.1022975
15       6 1/1/2012  100  0.95949406 -0.4755931
```

Although it does ignore the irrelevant variables (JUNK1, JUNK2) , the technique is too greedy. The new dataset should contain three observations on unit one because there are three unique combinations of UNIT + DATE + OUT1 when UNIT = 1. Is there a way to achieve this without writing a function?

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a `data.frame` to `duplicated`

In your case, you want to pass the first 3 columns of `test`

```
 test2 <- test[!duplicated(test[,1:3]),]
```

If you are using big data, and want to embrace `data.tables`, then you can set the key to be the first three columns (which you want to remove the duplicates from) and then use `unique`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(test)
# set the key
setkey(DT, UNIT,DATE,OUT1)
DTU <- unique(DT)
```

For more details on duplicates and data.tables see [Filtering out duplicated/non-unique rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table)

Comment: Since there is a `bigdata` tag it might be worth mentioning this post on removing duplicates from a `data.table` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Looks like we can do:

```
test2 <- test[!duplicated(test[,c("OUT1","DATE","UNIT")]),]
```

and it delivers the goods as well. So, we can just use the column names rather than 1:3 and the order doesn't matter

Comment: This is no different from my answer, apart from noting how `[` works, which is irrelevant to the `duplicated` component

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` from the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  distinct(UNIT, DATE, OUT1)
```

Or without the `%>%` pipe:

```
distinct(test, UNIT, DATE, OUT1)
```