# remove duplicate values based on 2 columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate values based upon matches in 2 columns in a dataframe, `v2` & `v4` must match between rows to be removed.

```
> df

   v1  v2  v3   v4  v5
1  7   1   A  100  98 
2  7   2   A  100  97
3  8   1   C   NA  80
4  8   1   C   78  75
5  8   1   C   78  62
6  9   3   C   75  75
```

For a result of

```
> df

   v1  v2  v3   v4  v5
1  7   1   A  100  98 
2  8   1   C   NA  80
3  8   1   C   78  75
4  9   3   C   75  75
```

I know I want something like:

```
df[!duplicated(df[v2] && df[v4]),]
```

but this doesn't work.

This question is specifically about dataframes, for those who have a data.table, see [Filtering out duplicated/non-unique rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table).

Comment: In the example you are providing, it seems that keys are `v1` and `v4` (the first column  actually represents the row names). Try `df[!duplicated(df[,c("v1","v4")]),]`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This will give you the desired result:

```
df [!duplicated(df[c(1,4)]),]
```

Comment: Hi what if you want to use its column name (e.g. v1 & v4) instead of the column numbers 1, 4 ?

Comment: @Bustergun you could use df[!duplicated(df[c("V1","V4")]),]