# Count number of unique values in two variables in r

Tags: r, aggregate

[image: dataset]

I have a dataset like this. I would like to count number of of times a customer visited according to the date in an whole year in R. (Using UniSA_Customer_No and Sale_Date)

There are few time a customer no and date are repeated. I need to group all the date and customer no and find how many times customer number has visited in whole year

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% count(UniSA_Customer_No, Sale_Date = year(as.Date(Sale_Date)))
```

In base R, use `table` :

```
table(df$UniSA_Customer_No, format(as.Date(df$Sale_Date), '%Y'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by "tabulating" each customer with:

```
table(year2014$UniSA_Customer_No)
```

It is possible to compare 2 variables for example:

```
tabulate(year2014$UniSA_Customer_No, year2014$Sale_Date)
```

However, in this case I'd suggest removing duplicates first (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909489/remove-duplicate-values-based-on-2-columns) for details).

```
#select data from the year 2014
year2014 <- year2014[grep("^2014-", year2014$Sale_Date),]
#extract only columns to define duplicates
cust_date <- cbind(year2014$UniSA_Customer_No, year2014$Sale_Date)
#detect duplicates
dup_rows <- duplicated(cust_date)
#subset to unique rows
year2014unique <- year2014[!dup_rows,]
#tabulate without duplicates (customers counted once per day)
table(year2014unique$UniSA_Customer_No, year2014unique$Sale_Date)
```

For minimal example:

```
> unique(c(1, 2, 3, 1))
[1] 1 2 3
> table(c(1, 2, 3, 1))

1 2 3 
2 1 1
```

There is no need for external packages to do this.