# Removing duplicates based on 3-4 columns (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate, stringr

I realize this might have been asked before but I am struggling to correctly remove duplicates in my df. I have used the method recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909489/remove-duplicate-values-based-on-2-columns), but it's not removing all duplicates.

#install packages

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(stringr)
library(textclean)
library(lubridate)
```

Here is my data:

```
dput(df[1:10,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)])
```

data output:

```
structure(list(username = c("Engineeer", "ftpofmpo", "sagood",
"ishtarsg", "Ohayo!", "Engineeer"), post = c("Engineers are si ginnas who recently graduated from Universities. No one stays as an Engineer like forever.\nEngineering is harder than Business but more fulfilling in the long run.\nEngineer > Manager > Director > Chief Technology Officer > Chief Executive Officer\n\tzero to sixty times",
"\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tEngineeer said:\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\tThen pick up Engineering. Its harder but more fulfilling in the long run. No one stays as an Engineer like forever.\nEngineer > Manager > Director > Chief Technical Officer > Chief Executive\n\t\t\n\t\tClick to expand...\n\t\n\nhave you seen the past list of president scholars?\nif minister salary pegg to engineer pay jialat liao... check out lky statement on y salary must be high",
"i thought engineering ish dominated by ceca?????", "Always opt to be a priest.",
"after CEO beome mayor then minister?", "\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tsagood said:\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\ti thought engineering ish dominated by ceca?????\n\t\t\n\t\tClick to expand...\n\t\nIf you fret Engineering its fine. Donate these good paying jobs to CECAs."
), date = structure(c(1622851200, 1622851200, 1622851200, 1622851200,
1622851200, 1622851200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct",
"POSIXt")), user_status = c("Supremacy Member", "Banned", "Member",
"Arch-Supremacy Member", "Great Supremacy Member", "Supremacy Member"
), treatment_implementation = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), month_year = c(2021.41666666667,
2021.41666666667, 2021.41666666667, 2021.41666666667, 2021.41666666667,
2021.41666666667), id = c(255, 296, 747, 389, 634, 255)), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To delete duplicate rows, I am removing based on the following three columns:

```
# Drop duplicate observations
df <-
df %>%
filter(duplicated(cbind(username, post, date)))
```

After running the code above, I still see duplicate rows when I inspect the data manually. Moreover, when I run the same code above again after the first duplicate removal attempt, it keeps deleting more rows which is confusing because I thought all duplicate rows should be deleted in one attempt (i.e. when running the code just once).

Comment: Since you are deleting duplicates, should you filter out them by adding `!`?  `df <-
df %>%
filter(!duplicated(cbind(username, post, date)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` function from the `dplyr` package to achieve your goal of filtering out duplicates based on specific columns.

```
df <- df %>%
  distinct(username, post, date, .keep_all = T)
```