# Setkey() and unique() for data.table in r 3.4.0 returns all rows in the data table not just the unique ones

Tags: r, data.table, unique

*I recently downloaded this version of R:*

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)library(data.table)

*The behavior for setkey() and unique() on data tables has changed. Previous versions of R (3.3.3) would not return 7 rows in the following example since there are two rows with V2=="D".
This seems like a big change - is this intended?*

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
+   V1=LETTERS[c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,5,7,1)],
+   V2=LETTERS[c(2,3,4,2,1,4,4,6,7,2)]
+ )
setkey(dt, "V2")
unique(dt)

   V1 V2
1:  B  A
2:  A  B
3:  A  C
4:  A  D
5:  C  D
6:  E  F
7:  G  G
str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
$ V1: chr  "B" "A" "A" "A" ...
$ V2: chr  "A" "B" "B" "B" ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
- attr(*, "sorted")= chr "V2"
```

Comment: What version of the `data.table` library are you using? (see `sessionInfo()` to verify). Check out this potentially breaking change from version 1.9.8+: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#potentially-breaking-changes. Perhaps you were using an older version of the library before? `unique()` now looks at all columns, not just key.

Comment: Don't use `+` and `>` if you want anyone to be able to test your code.

Comment: I'm using data.table_1.10.4 now same version as before. In the past unique() would look at all columns if the data table had no sort key otherwise it would just look at the key column and return the unique rows for the key column.

Comment: Here's another stackoverflow question with the same example from 4 years ago with a different result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table

Comment: OK - I see that a change was made. That's a pretty big change!