# Distinct in data.table as in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to use `data.table` for a better performance but dont know how to do the equivalent of `distinct %>% summarize` in `dplyr`. Any ideas how I could adapt the following code to `data.table`?

```
group_by_('x,y,z') %>%
distinct('h', .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
summarise(tot1 = sum(value1), tot2 = sum(value2))
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table

Comment: maybe, but how to do it in with the  bracket notation (group, distinct and sum)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the group, distinct, and sum in 2 steps with `data.table`. First, use `unique()` with the `by` argument set to your grouping and distinct variables. Then do the data.table equivalent of `summarize()` with just the grouping variables.

```
dfq = data_frame(
    g1 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), times = 12), 
    g2 = rep(c('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'), times = 9), 
    c3 = as.integer(30 * runif(36)), 
    d4 = rep(LETTERS[1:18], times = 2)
)

dtq = as.data.table(dfq)
dtq2 = unique(dtq, by = c("g1", "g2", "d4"))[
    , .(sum1 = sum(c3)), 
    by = c("g1", "g2")
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Data.table is not well documented and explained like dplyr .

Comment: @Fausto Re documentation, some explanation and examples for aggregation are in `vignette("datatable-intro")` and I guess they're open to feedback on it (eg, maybe `unique` belongs there).