# Efficient way to remove duplicate rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

It is straightforward to filter a `data.table` for unique or duplicated rows. An example for that is provided in [Filtering out duplicated/non-unique rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table).
I would like to know if there's a more efficient way than reassigning the data.table to a new object, which has the duplicated entries removed?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  V1=LETTERS[c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,5,7,1)],
  V2=LETTERS[c(2,3,4,2,1,4,4,6,7,2)]
)
filtered.dt <- unique(dt, by = "V2")
```

Is there perhaps a more efficient way than this reassignment?

Comment: So far you can't delete rows by reference in `data.table` (if that was the correct interpretation of your question). See [How to delete a row by reference in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790204/how-to-delete-a-row-by-reference-in-data-table), and corresponding open issue: [Delete rows by reference](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635).

Comment: Yes, that would be the correct interpretation, thanks for the link and the information. Marking it as a duplicate, but I think it's probably good to keep the question with the different heading.

Comment: @hannes101 is ``dt <- dt[!duplicated(dt),]`` also inefficient?

Comment: What I mean by inefficient is the reassignment of the data.table, which always happens, when using <-. Additionally, I think this is just another way to select the unique values, which should be equivalent.