# Removing rows in R only if they are duplicated in direct succession

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` indicating the position of an animal which looks something like this:

```
    Date       TimeStamp             Transponder Units
 1: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:13    DA2C614E    M2
 2: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:14    DA2C614E    M2
 3: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:14    DA2C614E    M2
 4: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:15    DA2C614E    M2
 5: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:15    DA2C614E    M2
 6: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:16    DA2C614E    M2
 7: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:40    DA2C614E   HM2
 8: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:40    DA2C614E   HM2
 9: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:49    DA2C614E    H2
10: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:18:02    DA2C614E    H1
11: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:18:04    DA2C614E    H1
12: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:19:19    DA2C614E    H1
13: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:25:29    DA2C614E   HM2
```

The Transponder indicates the individual and the Units the position. I would like to create a more sparse version of this data set by deleting the duplicated rows, but **only** those which are in succession. Essentially, because the successive duplicates just mean no movement. Meaning I would want my end results to be:

```
      Date       TimeStamp             Transponder Units
   1: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:13    DA2C614E    M2
   2: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:40    DA2C614E   HM2
   3: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:49    DA2C614E    H2
   4: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:18:02    DA2C614E    H1
   5: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:25:29    DA2C614E   HM2
```

I have tried working with `duplicated()`, but the problem is that this function deletes **all** duplicates, like for example the later repeated `HM2` entry. (I ran duplicated on a subset of Date, Transponder and Units):

```
> sample[!duplicated(sample[, c(1,3,4)]),]
         Date           TimeStamp Transponder Units
1: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:11:13    DA2C614E    M2
2: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:40    DA2C614E   HM2
3: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:12:49    DA2C614E    H2
4: 2021-08-15 2021-08-15 14:18:02    DA2C614E    H1
```

Any ideas on how to solve this "elegantly", i.e. without having to loop through this?

Comment: Please provide reproducible code for your data (you can use dput()).

Comment: Sorry, will do next time! First ever question... @sindri_baldur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rleid` from `data.table` we create a dummy-grouping variable, and with `distinct` from `dplyr` we remove the duplicates. In your data you may want to include `Transponder` in the `rleid` function, if it does vary in your real data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>% 
  mutate(dummy = rleid(Units)) %>% 
  distinct(dummy, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  select(-dummy)

        Date           TimeStamp Transponder Units
1 2021-08-15 2021-08-15-14:11:13    DA2C614E    M2
2 2021-08-15 2021-08-15-14:12:40    DA2C614E   HM2
3 2021-08-15 2021-08-15-14:12:49    DA2C614E    H2
4 2021-08-15 2021-08-15-14:18:02    DA2C614E    H1
5 2021-08-15 2021-08-15-14:25:29    DA2C614E   HM2
```

Using just `data.table` and no temporary variable you could do the following: `dt[!duplicated(rleid(Units)),]`, based on comments.

Comment: Thanks! rleid works perfectly! What's the advantage of using distinct over duplicated on the grouping dummy here? They both deliver the same results as far as I can see?

Comment: Great it worked. I  think that is just my habit of using the tidyverse framework. `rleid` is the key function in this solution, and you could use it in here in conjuction with `duplicated` or `unique` for example as well.

Comment: `data.table`-variant: `df <- df[unique(rleid(Units)),]`, there is no need for temp variables or deselection (or `dplyr` even).

Comment: unique does only give you the first 5 records. unique gives just a vector 1:5 (we have 5 groups), but then you subset the first 5 rows of your table. You need !duplicated to subset on your T/F's and keep the positions on what to keep.

Comment: Or we just take the first of each rleid's. It messes up a bit your order and adds the rleid column, but I think on large datasets, it can be more efficient. `dt[, .SD[1L], by = .(rleid(Units), Units)]`

Answer (score 0):

see [Filtering out duplicated/non-unique rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792527/filtering-out-duplicated-non-unique-rows-in-data-table?rq=1)

I think that if your data is **time indexed** this will work on your code:

```
unique(sample, by = "Date")
```

Example:

```
dt <- data.table(V1 = LETTERS[c(1,1,1,2,2,2)], V2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

   V1 V2
1:  A  1
2:  A  1
3:  A  1
4:  B  2
5:  B  2
6:  B  2
```

```
unique(dt, by = "V1")

   V1 V2
1:  A  1
2:  B  2
```

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work as it will also remove valid repeated entries.

Comment: If you change your example to V2 = c(1,2,1,2,2,2) you will see how the output will be the same as for V2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2) even though I would want the output to show the 1,2,1 sequence, as the ones are not in succession

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have a go at this using `data.table`, as you stated you are using it, presumably as your data is large, so this should be faster than the `dplyr` approach suggested. I do not have much experience with `data.table` so I wanted to try and this seems to work:

```r
# Cols to subset
cols <- c("Date", "Transponder", "Units")
lagcols <- paste0(cols, "_lag")

# Create lag
sample[, (lagcols) := shift(.SD, n = 1, fill = NA, type = "lag"), .SDcols = cols]

# Create boolean mask if row == previous row in selected columns
sample[, equals_previous := Date == Date_lag & Transponder == Transponder_lag & Units == Units_lag]

# Delete lag columns
sample[, (lagcols) := NULL]

# Subset only rows where they are not equal to the previous row
sample[(!equals_previous)]
```

There may be more elegant ways to do this in `data.table`, but if your data is of a significant size this should at least be faster than converting to a `data.frame` and using `dplyr`.