# Print the unique values of all columns of a dataset in R

Tags: r, unique

So what I've bee trying to do here is to get the unique values of all the columns,

```
 i = 1
for (i in i : ncol(usd_empatt_dataset))
{
  cat(names(usd_empatt_dataset[i])," has ", colSums(is.na(usd_empatt_dataset[i])),"\n")
}
```

The code executes fine.

But i get the following error

```
Error in print.default(names(usd_empatt_dataset[i]), " has ", unique(usd_empatt_dataset[3]),  : 
  invalid 'digits' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In print.default(names(usd_empatt_dataset[i]), " has ", unique(usd_empatt_dataset[3]),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Kindly share some fix and knowledge on the same.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Maybe `lapply(myData, unique)` ?

Comment: or `apply( dyData, 2, unique )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unique() for more than one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790732/unique-for-more-than-one-variable).

Comment: At the moment I think your code is getting count of non NA values in every column... What is the expected output?