# How to list all unique values for each category

Tags: r

I have two columns, first is the function of the Business (Upstream, Downstream , Midstream etc) and the other is the city those functions operate in. There are a ton of other functions amd cities but I have made it smaller here and it looks something like this:

```
Function      City
DownStream   Edmonton
Downstream   Edmonton
upstream     Edmonton
Upstream     Calgary
Midstream    Calgary
Midstream    Calgary
Midtream     Edmonton
Upstream     Vancouver
```

I know the unique() function will return the unqiue values I am looking for, however I am having trouble creating something that will group the Function column and then listing the unique Cities for each Function.

Something like this as the end results:

```
Functions  City

Downstream Edmonton


Midstream  Edmonton 
           Calgary 


Upstream   Edmonton
           Calgary
           Vancouver
```

Here is some sample data to work from

```
# Create sample data
Function=c("DownStream", "DownStream", "Upstream", "Upstream", "Midstream", 
           "Midstream", "Midstream", "Upstream")
City=c("Edmonton", "Edmonton", "Edmonton", "Calgary","Calgary", "Calgary",
       "Edmonton", "Vancouver")
df <- data.frame(Function, City)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unique() for more than one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790732/unique-for-more-than-one-variable)

Comment: Are you looking for an output where the grouping variable only appears once? Or do you want a `data.frame` with the unique combinations?

Comment: Each Functions can appear only once or more, but each unique cities should appear once for each Functions

Comment: Is the inconsistent naming and capitalization intentional?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first getting the unique rows and than replacing the duplicates with NA.

```
# Create sample data
Function=c("DownStream", "DownStream", "Upstream", "Upstream", "Midstream", 
           "Midstream", "Midstream", "Upstream")
City=c("Edmonton", "Edmonton", "Edmonton", "Calgary", "Calgary", "Calgary", 
       "Edmonton", "Vancouver")
df <- data.frame(Function, City)

# Get unique rows and replace duplicates with NA
unique_df <- unique(df)
unique_df[duplicated(unique_df[,"Function"]),"Function"] <- NA
print(unique_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a data frame in R, like `df=data.frame(Function, City)`, then simply `unique(Function, City)` will give the results.
Or use dplyr package, then run the following codes
`df %>% group_by(Function) %>% distinct(City)`.